# ¿Cómo obtener una fila unica para filas repetidas en RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

estoy trabajando con una base datos con 26 columnas (Tiempo, Region1:Region25) y 54464 filas. Algunas de estas filas son iguales y necesito eliminar esos duplicados.

**Mi df se ve algo así**
1 significa que entró, mientras que 0 significa que no entró. Hay regiones a las que entró varias veces, por ejemplo, la Región25 registró dos entradas.
En el df se observa que la primera región que cruzó fue la Region1, y la ultima la Region25

(Las regiones van desde la 1 hasta la 25 y el tiempo está registrado en milésimas de segundo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito **eliminar las filas duplicadas sin que se pierda el dato de cuántas veces entró a cada región**.
**Lo que espero es un resultado similar al siguiente:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con la función unique()

```
unique(data[,c("Region1", "Region2", "Region3", "Region4", "Region5", "Region6", "Region7", "Region8", "Region9", "Region10", "Region11", "Region12", "Region13", "Region14", "Region15", "Region16", "Region17", "Region18", "Region19", "Region20", "Region21", "Region22", "Region23", "Region24", "Region25")])
```

Pero ese codigo elimina los otros valores y toma como único el primer valor registrado. El problema es que esta tabla me indica que la ultima región por la que pasó fue la Region24, y este dato es incorrecto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a todos por su tiempo, espero que puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo con la función `distinct()` del paquete `dplyr`.

Primero recreo una tabla parecida a la tuya.

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
mis_datos <- data.frame(
    tiempo = sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE),
    reg1 = sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE),
    reg2 = sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE),
    reg24 = sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE),
    reg25 = sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE)
) %>%
    slice_sample(n = 15, replace = TRUE)
```

Así luce la tabla.

```r
mis_datos
#>    tiempo reg1 reg2 reg24 reg25
#> 1      42    0    1     1     0
#> 2      14    0    0     1     0
#> 3      79    0    0     0     0
#> 4      67    0    0     0     0
#> 5      43    1    1     1     0
#> 6      79    0    0     0     0
#> 7      31    1    0     1     0
#> 8      14    0    0     1     0
#> 9      14    0    0     1     0
#> 10     42    0    1     1     0
#> 11     67    0    0     0     0
#> 12     14    0    0     1     0
#> 13     25    0    1     0     0
#> 14     14    0    1     0     1
#> 15     42    0    1     1     0
```

Dentro de `distinct()` tienes que especificar de qué columnas quieres eliminar los duplicados. Entendí que en tu caso son todas las columnas, por eso especifico dentro de `across()` desde la primera hasta la última.

```r
mis_datos %>%
    distinct(across(tiempo:reg25))
#>   tiempo reg1 reg2 reg24 reg25
#> 1     42    0    1     1     0
#> 2     14    0    0     1     0
#> 3     79    0    0     0     0
#> 4     67    0    0     0     0
#> 5     43    1    1     1     0
#> 6     31    1    0     1     0
#> 7     25    0    1     0     0
#> 8     14    0    1     0     1
```

Por favor para futuras preguntas es mejor postear una manera de recrear tus datos, usar imágenes dificulta que se te pueda ayudar pronto. Como ejemplo puedes usar `dput()` especificando el nombre de tus datos (mejor si es con una versión pequeña que muestre el problema que quieres resolver).

```r
dput(mis_datos)
#> structure(list(tiempo = c(42L, 14L, 79L, 67L, 43L, 79L, 31L, 
#> 14L, 14L, 42L, 67L, 14L, 25L, 14L, 42L), reg1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
#> 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), reg2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
#> 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), reg24 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
#> 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), reg25 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
#> 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L
#> ))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>